# Laravel 6.0 with google charts can't show data

Tags: laravel, charts

I have a problem with Laravel 6.0 and Google Charts, I can't represent the data that I have in my database I have this function

```
public function index()
{

$data = DB::table('incidencias')
   ->select(
    DB::raw('requiere_rep as requiere_rep'),
    DB::raw('count(*) as number'))
   ->groupBy('requiere_rep')
   ->get();
 $array[] = ['Requiere_rep', 'Number'];
 foreach($data as $key => $value)
 {
  $array[++$key] = [$value->requiere_rep, $value->number];
 }
    return view('Incidencias.index')->with('requiere_rep', json_encode($array));
 }
```

And this is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var analytics = <?php echo $requiere_rep; ?>
google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(analytics);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1,
                   { calc: "stringify",
                     sourceColumn: 1,
                     type: "string",
                     role: "annotation" },
                   2]);

  var options = {
    title: "TOP INCIDENCIAS POR CLIENTES",
    width: 380,
    height: 180,
    bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
    legend: { position: "none" },
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
  chart.draw(view, options);
```

}

This is my Html

```
<div id="columnchart_values" style="width: 900px; height: 300px; margin-top: 10%; margin-left: -431%;"></div>
```

Can somebody help me? thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, here is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var analytics = <?php echo $requiere_rep; ?>

google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart()
{
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(analytics);
var options = {
title : 'INCIDENCIAS POR REGIONES'
};
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('pie_chart'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `{{ }}` and `{!! !!}` syntax available in Blade templates. It is also better to just pass the data without `json_encode` to the view so you still have a manipulatable array, and then use:

`{!! json_encode($var) !!}` or the Blade helper `@json($var)` to echo your data into javascript like so:

```js
<script>
    var myvar = @json($array);
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for answer, but I don't understand you at all... where I have to put the variable in my code?

Comment: are you getting javascript errors? Try to debug that in the browser, my guess its that its caused by `var analytics = <?php echo $requiere_rep; ?>`.

Comment: I didn't get any error, the chart doesn't appear.. that is my problem